# Исправление меню на jQuery

Tags: jquery, menu

Здравствуйте, код меню с вложенными подпунктами, все работает. Но после наведения выпадает меню и больше не исчезает (только если навести на другое). Хочу чтобы при отведении мышки в от меню оно исчезало.

```js
var ddaccordion={

 

 contentclassname:{}, //object to store corresponding contentclass name based on headerclass



 expandone:function(headerclass, selected){ //PUBLIC function to expand a particular header

  this.toggleone(headerclass, selected, "expand")

 },



 collapseone:function(headerclass, selected){ //PUBLIC function to collapse a particular header

  this.toggleone(headerclass, selected, "collapse")

 },



 expandall:function(headerclass){ //PUBLIC function to expand all headers based on their shared CSS classname

  var $=jQuery

  var $headers=$('.'+headerclass)

  $('.'+this.contentclassname[headerclass]+':hidden').each(function(){

   $headers.eq(parseInt($(this).attr('contentindex'))).trigger("evt_accordion")

  })

 },



 collapseall:function(headerclass){ //PUBLIC function to collapse all headers based on their shared CSS classname

  var $=jQuery

  var $headers=$('.'+headerclass)

  $('.'+this.contentclassname[headerclass]+':visible').each(function(){

   $headers.eq(parseInt($(this).attr('contentindex'))).trigger("evt_accordion")

  })

 },



 toggleone:function(headerclass, selected, optstate){ //PUBLIC function to expand/ collapse a particular header

  var $=jQuery

  var $targetHeader=$('.'+headerclass).eq(selected)

  var $subcontent=$('.'+this.contentclassname[headerclass]).eq(selected)

  if (typeof optstate=="undefined" || optstate=="expand" && $subcontent.is(":hidden") || optstate=="collapse" && $subcontent.is(":visible"))

   $targetHeader.trigger("evt_accordion")

 },



 expandit:function($targetHeader, $targetContent, config, useractivated){

  $targetContent.slideDown(config.animatespeed, function(){config.onopenclose($targetHeader.get(0), parseInt($targetHeader.attr('headerindex')), $targetContent.css('display'), useractivated)})

  this.transformHeader($targetHeader, config, "expand")

 },



 collapseit:function($targetHeader, $targetContent, config, isuseractivated){

  $targetContent.slideUp(config.animatespeed, function(){config.onopenclose($targetHeader.get(0), parseInt($targetHeader.attr('headerindex')), $targetContent.css('display'), isuseractivated)})

  this.transformHeader($targetHeader, config, "collapse")

 },



 transformHeader:function($targetHeader, config, state){

  $targetHeader.addClass((state=="expand")? config.cssclass.expand : config.cssclass.collapse) //alternate btw "expand" and "collapse" CSS classes

  .removeClass((state=="expand")? config.cssclass.collapse : config.cssclass.expand)

  if (config.htmlsetting.location=='src'){ //Change header image (assuming header is an image)?

   $targetHeader=($targetHeader.is("img"))? $targetHeader : $targetHeader.find('img').eq(0) //Set target to either header itself, or first image within header

   $targetHeader.attr('src', (state=="expand")? config.htmlsetting.expand : config.htmlsetting.collapse) //change header image

  }

  else if (config.htmlsetting.location=="prefix") //if change "prefix" HTML, locate dynamically added ".accordprefix" span tag and change it

   $targetHeader.find('.accordprefix').html((state=="expand")? config.htmlsetting.expand : config.htmlsetting.collapse)

  else if (config.htmlsetting.location=="suffix")

   $targetHeader.find('.accordsuffix').html((state=="expand")? config.htmlsetting.expand : config.htmlsetting.collapse)

 },



 urlparamselect:function(headerclass){

  var result=window.location.search.match(new RegExp(headerclass+"=((\\d+)(,(\\d+))*)", "i")) //check for "?headerclass=2,3,4" in URL

  if (result!=null)

   result=RegExp.$1.split(',')

  return result //returns null, [index], or [index1,index2,etc], where index are the desired selected header indices

 },



 getCookie:function(Name){ 

  var re=new RegExp(Name+"=[^;]+", "i") //construct RE to search for target name/value pair

  if (document.cookie.match(re)) //if cookie found

   return document.cookie.match(re)[0].split("=")[1] //return its value

  return null

 },



 setCookie:function(name, value){

  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; path=/"

 },



 init:function(config){

 document.write('<style type="text/css">\n')

 document.write('.'+config.contentclass+'{display: none}\n') //generate CSS to hide contents

 document.write('<\/style>')

 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  ddaccordion.urlparamselect(config.headerclass)

  var persistedheaders=ddaccordion.getCookie(config.headerclass)

  ddaccordion.contentclassname[config.headerclass]=config.contentclass //remember contentclass name based on headerclass

  config.cssclass={collapse: config.toggleclass[0], expand: config.toggleclass[1]} //store expand and contract CSS classes as object properties

  config.revealtype=/^(click)|(mouseover)$/i.test(config.revealtype)? config.revealtype.replace(/mouseover/i, "mouseenter") : "click"

  config.htmlsetting={location: config.togglehtml[0], collapse: config.togglehtml[1], expand: config.togglehtml[2]} //store HTML settings as object properties

  config.oninit=(typeof config.oninit=="undefined")? function(){} : config.oninit //attach custom "oninit" event handler

  config.onopenclose=(typeof config.onopenclose=="undefined")? function(){} : config.onopenclose //attach custom "onopenclose" event handler

  var lastexpanded={} //object to hold reference to last expanded header and content (jquery objects)

  var expandedindices=ddaccordion.urlparamselect(config.headerclass) || ((config.persiststate && persistedheaders!=null)? persistedheaders : config.defaultexpanded)

  if (typeof expandedindices=='string') //test for string value (exception is config.defaultexpanded, which is an array)

   expandedindices=expandedindices.replace(/c/ig, '').split(',') //transform string value to an array (ie: "c1,c2,c3" becomes [1,2,3]

  var $subcontents=$('.'+config["contentclass"])

  if (expandedindices.length==1 && expandedindices[0]=="-1") //check for expandedindices value of [-1], indicating persistence is on and no content expanded

   expandedindices=[]

  if (config["collapseprev"] && expandedindices.length>1) //only allow one content open?

   expandedindices=[expandedindices.pop()] //return last array element as an array (for sake of jQuery.inArray())

  if (config["onemustopen"] && expandedindices.length==0) //if at least one content should be open at all times and none are, open 1st header

   expandedindices=[0]

  $('.'+config["headerclass"]).each(function(index){ //loop through all headers

   if (/(prefix)|(suffix)/i.test(config.htmlsetting.location) && $(this).html()!=""){ //add a SPAN element to header depending on user setting and if header is a container tag

    $('<span class="accordprefix"></span>').prependTo(this)

    $('<span class="accordsuffix"></span>').appendTo(this)

   }

   $(this).attr('headerindex', index+'h') //store position of this header relative to its peers

   $subcontents.eq(index).attr('contentindex', index+'c') //store position of this content relative to its peers

   var $subcontent=$subcontents.eq(index)

   var needle=(typeof expandedindices[0]=="number")? index : index+'' //check for data type within expandedindices array- index should match that type

   if (jQuery.inArray(needle, expandedindices)!=-1){ //check for headers that should be expanded automatically (convert index to string first)

    if (config.animatedefault==false)

     $subcontent.show()

    ddaccordion.expandit($(this), $subcontent, config, false) //Last Boolean value sets 'isuseractivated' parameter

    lastexpanded={$header:$(this), $content:$subcontent}

   }  //end check

   else{

    $subcontent.hide()

    config.onopenclose($(this).get(0), parseInt($(this).attr('headerindex')), $subcontent.css('display'), false) //Last Boolean value sets 'isuseractivated' parameter

    ddaccordion.transformHeader($(this), config, "collapse")

   }

  })

  $('.'+config["headerclass"]).bind("evt_accordion", function(){ //assign custom event handler that expands/ contacts a header

    var $subcontent=$subcontents.eq(parseInt($(this).attr('headerindex'))) //get subcontent that should be expanded/collapsed

    if ($subcontent.css('display')=="none"){

     ddaccordion.expandit($(this), $subcontent, config, true) //Last Boolean value sets 'isuseractivated' parameter

     if (config["collapseprev"] && lastexpanded.$header && $(this).get(0)!=lastexpanded.$header.get(0)){ //collapse previous content?

      ddaccordion.collapseit(lastexpanded.$header, lastexpanded.$content, config, true) //Last Boolean value sets 'isuseractivated' parameter

     }

     lastexpanded={$header:$(this), $content:$subcontent}

    }

    else if (!config["onemustopen"] || config["onemustopen"] && lastexpanded.$header && $(this).get(0)!=lastexpanded.$header.get(0)){

     ddaccordion.collapseit($(this), $subcontent, config, fa) //Last Boolean value sets 'isuseractivated' parameter

    }

   })

  $('.'+config["headerclass"]).bind(config.revealtype, function(){

   if (config.revealtype=="mouseenter"){

    clearTimeout(config.revealdelay)

    var headerindex=parseInt($(this).attr("headerindex"))

    config.revealdelay=setTimeout(function(){ddaccordion.expandone(config["headerclass"], headerindex)}, config.mouseoverdelay || 0)

   }

   else{

    $(this).trigger("evt_accordion")

    return false //cancel default click behavior

   }

  })

  $('.'+config["headerclass"]).bind("mouseleave", function(){

   clearTimeout(config.revealdelay)

  })

  config.oninit($('.'+config["headerclass"]).get(), expandedindices)

  $(window).bind('unload', function(){ //clean up and persist on page unload

   $('.'+config["headerclass"]).unbind()

   var expandedindices=[]

   $('.'+config["contentclass"]+":visible").each(function(index){ //get indices of expanded headers

    expandedindices.push($(this).attr('contentindex'))

   })

   if (config.persiststate==false){ //persist state?

    expandedindices=(expandedindices.length==0)? '-1c' : expandedindices //No contents expanded, indicate that with dummy '-1c' value?

    ddaccordion.setCookie(config.headerclass, expandedindices)

   }

  })

 })

 }

}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
ddaccordion.init({
 headerclass: "headerbar", //Shared CSS class name of headers group
 contentclass: "submenu", //Shared CSS class name of contents group
 revealtype: "mouseover", //Reveal content when user clicks or onmouseover the header? Valid value: "click" or "mouseover
 mouseoverdelay: 200, //if revealtype="mouseover", set delay in milliseconds before header expands onMouseover
 collapseprev: true, //Collapse previous content (so only one open at any time)? true/false
 defaultexpanded: [], //index of content(s) open by default [index1, index2, etc] [] denotes no content
 onemustopen: false, //Specify whether at least one header should be open always (so never all headers closed)
 animatedefault: false, //Should contents open by default be animated into view?
 persiststate: true, //persist state of opened contents within browser session?
 toggleclass: ["", ""], //Two CSS classes to be applied to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively ["class1", "class2"]
 togglehtml: ["", "", ""], //Additional HTML added to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively  ["position", "html1", "html2"] (see docs)
 animatespeed: "fast", //speed of animation: integer in milliseconds (ie: 200), or keywords "fast", "normal", or "slow"
  oninit:function(headers, expandedindices){ //custom code to run when headers have initalized
//do nothing
},
onopenclose:function(header, index, state, isuseractivated){ //custom code to run whenever a header is opened or closed
//do nothing
}
 
})
</script>
```

Comment: Из-за того, что `document.cookie` недоступен в песочнице stack overflow - ваш пример не запускается. А http://jsfiddle.net не принимает `document.write` - в результате ваш пример крайне трудно воспроизвести в рамках веба

Comment: Я нечего не поняла и пока не особо могу разобраться тут. Вот ссылка на файл скрипта и стилей,  в файле categoryl  тоже кусок скрипта http://www.ex.ua/127216164632.

Comment: Мне кажется - вам лучше вообще поискать другой плагин под ваши нужды. Как-то слишком подозрительно, что скрипт по выводу меню зачем-то лезет в куки и пытается переписать документ. Плюс распространяется он странно, судя по вашей ссылке. Я бы с настороженностью отнесся